# Chars to Binary to Hex and Backwards in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, binary, hex

to explain my problem, let me first explain what i'm trying to do.

1. I have this example String here: "12345678XA3VLX4321"
2. I need to convert it to Binary, which outputs: "00110001 00110010 00110011 00110100 00110101 00110110 00110111 00111000 01011000 01000001 00110011 01010110 01001100 01011000 00110100 00110011 00110010 00110001"
3. Now i need to cut the first two bits of every 8-Bit binary sequence like this: "<s>00</s>110001 <s>00</s>110010 <s>00</s>110011 <s>00</s>110100 <s>00</s>110101 <s>00</s>110110 <s>00</s>110111 <s>00</s>111000 <s>01</s>011000 <s>01</s>000001 <s>00</s>110011 <s>01</s>010110 <s>01</s>001100 <s>01</s>011000 <s>00</s>110100 <s>00</s>110011 <s>00</s>110010 <s>00</s>110001" 
    
    Then i have "110001 110010 110011 110100 110101 110110 110111 111000 011000 000001 110011 010110 001100 011000 110100 110011 110010 110001"
4. Then i need to append two 6-Bit Binary Blocks "100000 100000", so i have: "110001 110010 110011 110100 110101 110110 110111 111000 011000 000001 110011 010110 001100 011000 110100 110011 110010 110001 100000 100000"
5. After that i need to convert the binary sequence from 4 to hex: "c72cf4d76df8601cd6318d33cb1820"
6. And as a final step, i have to add "da" to the hex sequence, so it looks like this: "dac72cf4d76df8601cd6318d33cb1820"

I wrote a program in Java, which can do that. Here is the code:

```
String input = txtInput.getText();
byte[] bytes = input.getBytes();
StringBuilder binary = new StringBuilder();

// generate Binary sequence out of characters
for (byte b : bytes) {
  int val = b;
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    binary.append((val & 128) == 0 ? 0 : 1);
    val <<= 1;
  }
  binary.append(' ');
}

String[] _arr = binary.toString().split("\\s");  // splits a string into an array, splitting by spaces

// delete first two characters of every binary sequence
for(int i = 0; i < _arr.length; i++) {
  _arr[i] = _arr[i].substring(2, 8);
}

String convertedArrayWithSpaces = convertArrayToStringMethodWithEmptySpace(_arr).toString(); // convert the array to a string
convertedArrayWithSpaces = convertedArrayWithSpaces + "100000 100000"; // append two spaces at the end of the string

String[] _arrFinal = convertedArrayWithSpaces.toString().split("\\s"); // splits a string into an array, splitting by spaces
String convertedArrayFinal = convertArrayToStringMethod(_arrFinal); // converts an array to a string without spaces
BigInteger b = new BigInteger(convertedArrayFinal, 2); // convert binary sequence to hex
String finalResult = "da" + b.toString(); // add "da" to the string
```

Now for my question. How can i convert the final result "dac72cf4d76df8601cd6318d33cb1820" back to the example text "12345678XA3VLX4321" of the beginning?

The problem i have with this, is in the 6-bit to 8-bit conversion part. I can't just guess if i need to add "00", "01", "10" or "11" the the 6-bit sequence.

But i know it is possible, because i could buy a very expensive software which can do that.

So i hope somebody can help me with this problem.

Thanks in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: Are the letters always in the same position in the original sequence? Because all of that is ASCII so you only need 7 bit out of the 8, which means `11`and `10` can never be the correct prefix that's missing. And since the binary representing numbers always starts with `00` you'll need `00` where numbers are and `01` where letters should be.

Comment: If the input string can be any any String consisting of numbers and letters at any position, then what you are trying to do is impossible. For example `"1"` expressed as a byte is `00110001` and `"q"` is `01110001`, so when you just cut off the first two bits you can no longer distinguish those 2 values as you already found out.

Comment: Thank you guys for your quick replies! The text and numbers are always in the same position, so it is possible to solve this like you guys suggested. Thank you very much!